# Binary to 16 Bit unsigned & 16 bit signed magnitude

Tags: decimal, unsigned-integer, signed-integer

I missed a day of class due to illness, so I checked out my profs. material for that day online and I'm stuck on this. His notes don't have an explanation on how to do it. I can do conversions between the masses (decimal to octal, hex, binary etc.), but I can't do this.

Any help? An example would really help me understand quickly. I'll post his slideshow example:

```
1010 0000 0100 0101 as an unsigned value
= (1 * 2^15) + (1 * 2^13) + (1 * 2^6) + (1 * 2^2) + (1 * 2^0)
= (32,768) + (8192) + (64) + (4) + (1)
= 32,768 + 8261 = 41,029 base 10



1010 0000 0100 0101 as a signed value
= - [(1 * 2^13) + (1 * 2^6) + (1 * 2^2) + (1 * 2^0)] 
= -8,261 base 10
```

I guess I should really attend class even when I'm sick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign is the 15th bit. So all you have to do is basically count places with ones (i.e.  2^place) and add them together.

Comment: Okay, so: 0100 1000 0001 = (1*2^10) + (1*2^7) + (1*2^0) = 1153 base 10. Is that correct?

Comment: Just a quick follow up, when you do the signed int. and the leading is a 1, it equals negative, equating the 2^place to -1, and continuing on to the next, is that correct? ex. 1100 1000 0001 = -(2^10 + 2^7 + 2^0)

Comment: Again correct, in signed notation, the left-most bit is used to indicate sign.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a signed integer and an unsigned integer is that one of the bits, in this case the leftmost bit is used to indicate if the value is positive or negatve. In this case, if the leftmost bit is 1, then the value is negative, and when the leftmost bit is 0 the value is positive.

So in the example that your professor gave,

```
1010 0000 0100 0101
```

can be interpreted as either a signed integer or an unsigned integer, depeding on the situation. When interpreted as a signed integer, the value evaluates out

```
(1 * 2^15) + (1 * 2^13) + (1 * 2^6) + (1 * 2^2) + (1 * 2^0) = 41092
```

When interpreted as an unsigned value, you get the sign from the leftmost bit and the value of the integer from the rest of the bits

```
- [(1 * 2^13) + (1 * 2^6) + (1 * 2^2) + (1 * 2^0)]  = - 8261
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! But here's my problem, I don't know how we got 2^15, 2^13 etc. I can't seem to find anything that explains that. I do know that 0000 = 0, 0001 = 1 etc.. But how is 1010 = 2^15 or 2^13 (when signed) when 1010 = 10? Sorry if this a noobish question.

Comment: See my answer: look at places where the 1's are

Comment: That arises when you convert a binary number to a decimal number. For example, converting 1011 to decimal is 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^8 or 11.

Answer (score 0):

this is so late but lol:
when you are given this 1010 0000 0100 0101 as an unsigned value

1010 0000 0100 0101
count each place value starting from right to left 0->

1  0 1  0  0  0  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1

15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

values 0-15 will be exponents in the operation and it is base 2 so you would do this operation
(1 * 2^15)+(0 * 2^14)+ (1 * 2^13) +...(1 * 2^0)
where 1 represents the digit, and 2^15 represents the conversion. as you can see anything times 0 results in 0 so we can ignore those and continue to add and the exponents of the 1 spot. and once you add all of those up you should result in the correct answer.
since it an unsigned value you dont need to worry about the first digit from the left being a +ve or a -ve.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).